# gcloud app deploy error too many files under .cache

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I have previously used on the Application I am developing **gcloud app deploy** with no errors - using Google Cloud Shell

However now I am getting the following

```
Error Response: [3] The directory [.cache/jedi/CPython-27-33] has too many files (greater than 1000).
```

I go to **App Engine -> Versions** and delete old versions but that did not help.

I look in latest version -> Tools -> Source and I see a directory

```
app-engine:
 .cache
  jedi
   CPython-27-33
    <4 .pkl directories each with too many files and no option to delete>
```

I will appreciate any tips or link to documentation on how to delete this directory and avoid problem in future so that I can successfully use gcloud app deploy from Google Cloud shell

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [gcloudignore file](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore) (similar to a `.gitignore` file) to avoid uploading a folder during the deployment.

You're facing the limit documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/how-requests-are-handled#quotas_and_limits) (1000 files per directory, 10000 files in total), and this limit is on GCP side. If you don't upload those files through a `.gcloudignore` file, you'll stop facing this error.

Aditionally if you need to upload >10k files to app engine you can contact [GCP Support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support) and ask for this limit to be increased for your project. They usually ask for a valid reason of why you need the new amount of files and take about a week to get this modified. Files per folder can't be increased.

Answer (score -6):

I went to

```
cd .cache\jedi\CPython-27-33
```

and executed

```
rm *
```

which resolved my issue

Comment: this is more like a temporary workaround than a proper solution. If the files were there once, the chance is they'll appear again eventually. Even if there will be < 1000 of them, there is really no reason to have them uploaded into the production environment, so I'd really recommend you to follow the advice from @Jofre and utilize `.gcloudignore` file

Comment: This is not an accurate solution, it is only temporal, what Jofre suggested is a better solution I have even used once